# python TypeError: unbound method zonecek() must be called with zoneAl instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

Tags: python-2.7, typeerror

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import time
import mechanize
import re
import sys
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
print "Hacknology iyi günler diler (:"
time.sleep(1)
yol = "http://www.zone-h.org/notify/single"
class zoneAl:
    def zonecek():
        attacker = raw_input("[*]Attacker: ")
        br.open(yol)
        br.select_form(nr=0)
        br.form["defacer"] = attacker
        oku = br.submit().read()
        print oku
zoneAl.zonecek()
```

I already tried the other solutions like this case. But they don't work. It says "TypeError: unbound method zonecek() must be called with zoneAl instance as first argument (got nothing instead)"

Comment: any help? plz, i still couldn't solve it

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is a very old question, but an answer better late than never. :)

Anyways, you need to instantiate the `zoneAl` class  first to an object before calling its methods:

```
class zoneAl:
    def __init__(self):
        print "initializing..."

    def zonecek(self):
        attacker = raw_input("[*]Attacker: ")
        br.open(yol)
        br.select_form(nr=0)
        br.form["defacer"] = attacker
        oku = br.submit().read()
        print oku

za = zoneAl()
za.zonecek()
```

Demo run:

```
Hacknology iyi günler diler (:
initializing...
[*]Attacker:
```

... awaits input.

Hope this helps.